How can I nest multiple routes in React Native app with expo-router?
Problem
I have multiple screens under a folder called (onboarding). In this folder there is a _layout.tsx and multiple screens. The issue is that, when I call this (onboarding) folder inside app/_layout.tsx, it does not find the route. The following warning pops out:
[Layout children]: No route named "(onboarding)" exists in nested children: ["_sitemap", "+not-found", "(onboarding)"] 
My File/Folder Structure
app/
  _layout.tsx
    (onboarding)/
      _layout.tsx
      LandingPageScreen.tsx
      LoginSignupScreen.tsx
      LoginScreen.tsx
      PhoneVerificationScreen.tsx

app/(onboarding)/_layout.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function OnboardingStackLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="LandingPageScreen" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginSignupScreen" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PhoneVerificationScreen"
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}


app/_layout.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="(onboarding)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

I am new to react native app development with expo and appreciate all the help!
I've already tried closing the app and re-running the metro bundler many times thinking it might be some build issue.
Edit: I think removing the stacks folder kind of worked but now it does not render the first route whicb is the LandingPageScreen.

Rename (onboarding)  to onboarding.
Folders with brackets will be ignored for the path https://docs.expo.dev/router/layouts/#groups

Renamed to onboarding but still not capturing the LandingPageScreen as the initial route.
However I found a workaround.
I removed the onboarding/LandingPageScreen.tsx, created an app/index.tsx file and imported the LandingPageScreen there which triggers the onboarding stack.
It is a little against the DRY principle so it would be great to just render the whole onboarding stack with LandingPageScreen.tsx as the initial route without an app/index.tsx file.

I think you can do it Like that:
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="onboarding" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

And rename app/(onboarding)/_layout.tsx to app/onboarding/_layout.tsx

I tried that way but still not capturing the initial route. It says "no route has been found" yet all the routes are in the onboarding folder.

not sure if it helps, but after changing the routes, you might need to restart the metro server for it to take effect
